# make keyboard accessible for client of remote server (Raspberry pi, php)

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, libretro

So here is what I wanted to do. I have an Apache2 server up and running on my raspberry pi 3, which is currently serving as a webradio using php commands and mpd/mpc. The raspberry is also connected via HDMI to a display.

I now like to have another page on the webserver which let's me start different roms in an emulator and display the output signal on the display connected to the remote server and and also lets me use a controller connected also to the remote server.

This is what I have done so far.

1. I have successfully installed Retroarch which is up and running.
2. I used `exec("export DISPLAY=:0.0; retroarch -c /home/pi/path/to/config -L /home/pi/path/to/libretro/core /home/pi/path/to/rom")` to start the emulator on the remote sever.

The problem is as follows. Even though I started the emulation successfully on the screen I cannot use the input devices connected to the remote server. **How can I make the input devices of the server accessible with a php-command or something else?** Can somebody point me to a solution to achieve this? Also the exec-command does not seem to accept my arguments besides the config file argument. I guess it has to do with user rights. But I am really stuck at this point.

Thanks for any replies.

Disclaimer: This is my first post. So I am sorry for bad terminology.

Comment: You might want a VNC connection. Probably your question is better placed on https://serverfault.com/ or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ The solution does not seem to be PHP or Apache related (as tagged in the question).

Comment: Nevertheless, +1 for the effort to form a proper, verbose question providing the information what to achieve and what you've done so far.

Comment: Thank you @Quasimodo's clone. I will check that out. The thing with VNC is, that even with x11vnc I am not able to display the output of the screen properly.